# Repeats the previous item between n and m times in wingrep

Tags: regex

I tried the following regular expression in wingrep 2.3:

```
[A-Za-z0-9]{1,5}cd77
```

But the search returns empty, even when I do have the following string ***testcd77*** inside txt file that I am searching.

Comment: What file specification pattern are you using?  Does it match *.txt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Regular Expression Lookup tab on the Search Criteria dialog for my copy of Windows Grep doesn't offer {} as a supported feature.  So I think you're stuck with unrolling the search string to

```
[A-Za-z0-9]([A-Za-z0-9]([A-Za-z0-9]([A-Za-z0-9]([A-Za-z0-9])?)?)?)?cd77
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately wingrep does not support {}. I used your example. I just wish there would be a shorter solution.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing in the [wingrep documentation](http://www.wingrep.com/Help/html/search-regexp.htm) indicates that they support this kind of interval expression. You might be simply unable to do it.

Some regex engines that do support those expressions require the curly braces to be escaped, so you can try this: `[A-Za-z0-9]\{1,5\}cd77`.  But if that doesn't work then I suspect you are out of luck.